# Redefine foreign key name for all associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys, sti

I have **an STI** model with many associations:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many :things
  has_many :other_things
  # ... a lot of `has_many`
end
```

Then I add **non STI** model as nested just to add some specific behaviour to `MyModel` without extending it directly:

```
class Nested < MyModel
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

But then my associations don't work. They have `my_model_id` column because they refer to `MyModel` and they should refer to `Nested` as well. But all these `has_many`'s expect to use `nested_id` column as a foreign key (it depends on class name).

I could've typed inside `class Nested`:

```
has_many :things, foreign_key: 'my_model_id'
has_many :other_things, foreign_key: 'my_model_id'
```

But if it's possible, **how to specify the foreign key for all the associations at once** in `Nested` class?

Comment: Inheritance is for specialization, and subclasses should be usable anywhere their superclasses are. If `Nested` is not STI, it should not be inheriting from something that is. If you state your actual goal in creating `Nested`, maybe we can help you with your design.

Comment: @Kristján, no, this is not a design problem and I'm aware of purposes of inheritance and STI as well. But there are many different cases in the programming when circumstances are over conventions. The example fits my needs one hundred percent. The question is only about redefining all foreign keys at once

Comment: Everything is a design problem :)

Comment: Well, It might be in Rails itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution might be is not recommended, but it works. Here it is:

```
class Nested < MyModel
  def self.name
    MyModel.name
  end
end
```

`ActiveRecord` will be looking for `my_model_id` foreign key for all the associations defined or redefined in `Nested` and `MyModel` classes.

Comment: If smb knows the drawbacks of this approach, let me know

Answer (score 2):

If all your `has_many` associations are declared on `MyModel`, you should be fine, or you may benefit from upgrading Rails; the following works perfectly for me in 4.2.4. Rails uses the class that declares `has_many` to generate the `foreign_key`, so even when `Nested` inherits, `:things` still get looked up by `my_model_id`.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end

class MyA < MyModel
end

class Nested < MyModel
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_model
end
```

```irb
> m = MyModel.create
 => #<MyModel id: 1, type: nil, created_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:16", updated_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:16">
> m.things.create
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Thing id: 1, my_model_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:19", updated_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:19">]>
> n = Nested.create
 => #<Nested id: 2, type: nil, created_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:27", updated_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:27">
> n.things.create
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Thing id: 2, my_model_id: 2, created_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:32", updated_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:32">]>
> n.reload.things
  Nested Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "my_models".* FROM "my_models" WHERE "my_models"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Thing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" WHERE "things"."my_model_id" = ?  [["my_model_id", 2]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Thing id: 2, my_model_id: 2, created_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:32", updated_at: "2015-12-22 02:21:32">]>
```

---

If you're giving `Nested` its own `has_many` associations, the code that generates foreign keys is pretty deep and inaccessible. You end up in the [`HasManyReflection`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L575), which either uses the `foreign_key` (or `as`) option declared on your `has_many` or derives it from the class name. There's no obvious way to customize those methods unless you do something inadvisable like override `Nested.name`.

[`foreign_key`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L305-L307):

```
def foreign_key
  @foreign_key ||= options[:foreign_key] || derive_foreign_key
end
```

[`derive_foreign_key`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L556-L564):

```
def derive_foreign_key
  if belongs_to?
    "#{name}_id"
  elsif options[:as]
    "#{options[:as]}_id"
  else
    active_record.name.foreign_key
  end
end
```

So the simplest way to go about this might just be a loop:

```
class Nested < MyModel
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  %i[things other_things].each do |association|
    has_many association, foreign_key: 'my_model_id'
  end
end
```

Or if you're feeling metaprogrammy, redefine `has_many`:

```
class Nested < MyModel
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  def self.has_many(klass, options={})
    options.reverse_merge!(foreign_key: 'my_model_id')
    super
  end

  has_many :things
  has_many :other_things
end
```

Comment: Well, what I'm doing is exactly that 'inadvisable overriding `Nested.name`'